# Coincidence of directional derivatives and derivatives along paths?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$

Let $\Phi:\R^2 \to \R$ be a function which has partial derivatives at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Let $\al:I \to \R^2$ be a path satisfying:

$\al(0)=(x_0,y_0),\dot \al(0)=v=(v_1,v_2)\neq (0,0)$.

Assume $\Phi \circ \al$ is differentiable at $t=0$ and the directional derivative  of $\Phi$ at direction $v$ ($d_v \Phi(x_0,y_0)$) exists.

Is it true that $(\Phi \circ \al)'(0)=d_v \Phi(x_0,y_0)$?

**Update:**

As noted by user251257, if $\Phi$ is Lipschitz then both derivatives agree. So, in order to find a counter-example (where they differ) we need to search for non-Lipschitz functions, which still has partial derivatives at the **point** $(x_0,y_0)$.

This is not trivial, since a function with bounded partial derivatives is Lipschitz (as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257553/a-multivariate-function-with-bounded-partial-derivatives-is-lipschitz)). So, our search is narrowed down to functions which do not have partial derivatives in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, or that there partial derivatives are unbounded in some neighbourhood of it.

**Note:**

In general, it can happen that either one of $(\Phi \circ \al)'(0),d_v \Phi(x_0,y_0)$ exists without the other.

**Example 1: $d_v \Phi(x_0,y_0)$ exists ,$(\Phi \circ \al)'(0)$ does not.**
(essentially taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367774/show-that-a-function-has-directional-derivatives-at-a-point-but-is-not-different))

$(x_0,y_0)=(0,0),
\Phi(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{x^2y}{x^4 +y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq 0$}\\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$} \\
\end{cases}, y(x)=x^2
$

$\Phi$ has directional derivatives at every direction at $(0,0)$, but for $\al(x)=(x,x^2)=(x,y(x))$ we get: $F(x)=\Phi \circ \al(x)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq 0$}\\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$} \\
\end{cases}
$
 is not differentiable at $x_0=0$.

**Example 2: $(\Phi \circ \al)'(0)$ exists ,$d_v \Phi(x_0,y_0)$ does not.**

**Update: this exmaple is wrong! I am not sure yet if a suitable example exists**

Take $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0),\al(t)=(t,t^3+t),\Phi(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$, $\Phi$ has partial derivatives ($\Phi_x(0,0)=\Phi_y(0,0)=0)$. $\Phi(\al(t))=\sqrt{t^4+t^2}$,so $(\Phi \circ \al)'(0)=1$. However, the directional derivative at direction $v=(1,1)$ does not exist.

Comment: So you want to know if $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(\alpha(0) + t \dot\alpha(0))|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\Phi(\alpha(t))|_{t=0}$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, exactly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is true for all paths exactly when $\Phi$ is differentiable. (This is more or less the definition.) Unless you consider a function which are differentiable along some paths and not along others (like the two examples).

Comment: @tomasz: If $\Phi$ is differentiable this is indeed immediate. If it is not differentiable, I want to know, if for every path along $\Phi$ is differentiable, the derivative must be equal to the directional derivative, i.e to the derivative along the linear path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Phi$ is Lipschitz continuous on a neighborhood of $\alpha(0)$, then both derivatives do agree.

**Updated counter example:**

Consider following example: 
\begin{align}
\Phi(x,y) &= \sqrt[3]{xy}, \\  
\alpha(t) &= (t(1-t), t^2). 
\end{align}
Then, we have $\Phi(\alpha(t)) = t\sqrt[3]{1-t}$. On the other hand we have $\alpha'(0) = (1,0)$ and $\Phi(\alpha(0) + t\alpha'(0)) = \Phi(t, 0) = 0$. So both derivatives differ.

Comment: Your example is interesting. I think I have learned something from it. Thanks. However, your function has a directional derivative in only one direction, $(0,1)$ (up to scaling) except zero. I am interested to know if this situation is possible for a function which has directional derivatives at two different directions. (That's why I specified the function must have partial derivatives).

Comment: @AsafShachar: Ah. I missed that $\Phi$ should have partial derivatives. I will improve the answer later

Comment: I have updated the question, to direct future attempts. In particular I have specified some limitations on the nature of potential candidates, which follow from your observation bout Lipschitzity. (You might find it helpful to have a look).

Comment: @AsafShachar I updated the counter example