# Derivative of matrix valued function $f(A)=AA^T$

Tags: matrices, manifolds, differential-topology, matrix-calculus

This is part of a larger proof on the orthonormal group viewed as a manifold. I have never done anything with matrix calculus and am trying to find $df$ where 
$$
f(A)=AA^T
$$
where 
$$
f:M_{n\times n}\to S(n)
$$
wehre $S(n)$ are the symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. So 
we should have 
$$
df:M_{n\times n}\to T_pS(n)
$$
where $p\in S(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: If you already know that $df$ exists, you can compute it as the directional derivative
$$
df_A(V) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(A+tV) - f(A)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(A+tV)(A+tV)^T - A A^T}{t} = \cdots
$$

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! What requires knowing that $df$ exists? It seems that if this limit exists for an arbitrary $V$ it should be differentiable no?

Comment: Even in multivariable calculus on $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are functions all of whose directional derivatives exist, but still fail to be differentiable.  (See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367774/show-that-a-function-has-directional-derivatives-at-a-point-but-is-not-different) for an example.)  Basically, directional derivatives are computed along lines, but the derivative along other curves may still not exist.

Comment: ah of course, my fault